# Java and PHP password generation working together

Tags: java, php, passwords, bukkit

I'm working on a Spigot/Bukkit plugin that will create a new table and store a randomly generated admin password in that table if that table did not exist.

I want to use the same method of checking the password in PHP as generating the password in Java. I'm not sure how to convert my PHP into Java.

PHP Password Checker / Generator

`$clean_password` would be the randomly generated string that needs to be encrypted.

```
$password_salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));
$hashed_password = hash('sha256', $clean_password . $password_salt);

for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) {
    $hashed_password = hash('sha256', $hashed_password . $password_salt);
}
```

How can I convert this into Java?

I thought about making some sort of an API on a website that would return the hashed password and the salt and I could just get the contents of the page and use it in the Java. The problem with this is that I'm releasing this to other people so I don't want them to have to depend on an API and would rather have it done in-line.

Comment: When I was dealing with this a bit ago I used this: https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing

Comment: Randomly generating passwords is a security risk, use a one-time access url that can be used to reset the password